# SQLite no release memory after delete

Tags: sqlite

Excuse for English

I using SQLite and test it. Insert multi-million row for testing speed. and deletes rows after  any insert.

But i know my database size is 33.0 MB..... now database is empty. but size on disk is 33 MB.
**WHY?**

can you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The VACUUM command rebuilds the entire database. There are several
>   reasons an application might do this:
>
> Unless SQLite is running in "auto_vacuum=FULL" mode, when a large amount of data is deleted from the database file it leaves behind
>   empty space, or "free" database pages. This means the database file
>   might be larger than strictly necessary. Running VACUUM to rebuild the
>   database reclaims this space and reduces the size of the database
>   file.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html